# When finding the LCM of two numbers, why is one number left out of multiplying when it is repeated in the multiples?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

For example, the LCM of 10, 24.  In factoring the two numbers, there are 4 twos, one 3, and one 5.  But, in using compact or exponents to find the LCM, the correct form is 2 cube, multiplied by 3, multiplied by 5, which is 120.  However, I get confused because there are 4 twos in factoring both numbers.  So, why is it not 2 to the fourth power instead of 2 cube?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If $a=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ and $b=\prod p_i^{b_i}$ then $\text {lcm}(a,b)=\prod p_i^{\max (a_i,b_i)}$.  Nothing is "left out".

Comment: In your example:  $10=2\times 5$ and  $24=2^3\times 3$ so $\text {lcm}(10,24)=2^3\times 3\times 5=120$.

Comment: See the linked proofs, in particular $\,p^j,p^k\mid p^i \iff j,k\le i \iff \max(j,k)\le i\ \ $